# Precedence of X-Robots-Tag header vs robots meta tag

Tags: http-headers, meta-tags, nofollow, noindex

I've placed the following `Header` in my vhost config:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

The goal here is to just disable search engines from indexing my testing environment. The site is Wordpress and there is a plugin installed to manage per-page the meta robots settings. For example:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

So my question is, which directive will take precedence over the other since both are being set on every page?

Comment: Great question. My suspicion is that, since `index`,`follow` are the *default* values, any `noindex`,`nofollow` directives that show up, whether in header or meta, will trump it. But I'd like to hear a definitive answer. Adding  bounty...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure if a definitive answer can be given to the question, as the behavior may be implementation-dependent (on the robot side).

However, I think there is reasonable evidence that `X-Robots-Tag` will take precedence over `<meta name="robots" ...`. See :

One significant difference between the `X-Robots-Tag` and the `robots` meta directive is:

- `X-Robots-Tag` is part of the **HTTP** protocol header.
- `<meta name="robots" ...` is part of the **HTML** document header.

Therefore the the `X-Robots-Tag` belongs to HTTP protocol layer, while `<meta name="robots" ...` belongs to the HTML protocol layer.

[image: Protocol capture]

As they belong to a different protocol layer, they will not be parsed simultaneously by the (robot) client getting the page: The HTTP layer will be parsed first, and the HTML in a later step.

(Also, it should be noted that `X-Robots-Tag` and `<meta name="robots" ...` are not suppported by all robots. Google and Yahoo/Bing suppport both, but according to [this](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/support-for-x-robots-tag-http-header-and-robots-HTML-meta-tag) some support only `<meta name="robots" ...`, others support neither.)

Summary :

- if supported by the robot, `X-Robots-Tag` will be processed first ; restrictions (noindex, nofollow) apply (and `<meta name="robots" ...` is ignored).
- else, `<meta name="robots" ...` directive applies.

Comment: The way this is explained makes perfect sense to me and I would have to agree with the facts. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: In my case (http header contains X-Robots-Tag as "noindex, nofollow" AND html document head contains robots meta tag as  "index,follow"), I was expecting that page would be removed from search results. BUT after waiting 3 days it seems doesn't work. Below answer from @Dan may be correct. So I will modify the html head to make it compatible with http header X-Robots-Tag and will observe the results.

Answer (score 4):

Just an update to Dan's experience, I also have both the

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

and

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

on my one of my Wordpress sites, and a check in Google Search Console confirmed that the noindex in X-Robots-Tag is taking precedence as the pages have been crawled and but aren't indexed. So the logic in the correct answer is indeed, correct.

Answer (score 2):

In my recent experience, when Google sees mixed-messages it prefers positive action by default - ie - it favours indexing - meanwhile will flag the issue as a critical error/warning in your webmaster tools console if you have one.

see your site's status in google here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/

see you site's status in bing here: http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster (note that yahoo search is now powered by bing)

Google takes this positive-by-default action because lots of site owners unwittingly have a dodgy cms semi-blocking robots and we know how google loves to accumulate as much data as it can - any excuse!

if the technical settings are erroneous they're liable to be totally disregarded, and we know how search engines index and follow by default when no settings are specified.