# Testing a website offline

Tags: html, indexing

I have been messing around for 3 hours with XAMPP and WAMP and I can't seem to get it to fully work with my website. So my alternative is to buy a cheap host just for testing but I have one concern. I was thinking of creating a subdirectory such as www.example.com/testsite/ and upload it there but I don't want it to get indexed by Google before I make all the changes/fixes. And after I'm done, move it to public_html. How long does it take for Google to index pages?

Comment: this might help https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I suggest you to take a look at vagrant.

Comment: A google bot won't index your site if it can't even find it. Make sure not to leave any public links to it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a robot text file with contents

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.

Check the [Robots](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Info regarding where to put the file

On a [Shared host](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/shared.html)

On a [Virtual host](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/virtual.html)

Comment: So it's as easy as creating a text file called robot and putting those texts in it? And then just put it in the same directory where index.html is?

Comment: you just need to put this in the root directory of your website

Answer (score 1):

You may use a robot.txt file.

http://www.robotstxt.org/

Here you can find the very same question: [Stop Google from indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390368/stop-google-from-indexing)

**EDIT**: I don't know you knowledge, but in my very humble opinion, I suggest you to create a virtual machine (virtualbox + a simple linx distro). A more easier solution I can suggest, is [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com). This will open your mind to a new dev/test approach. Hope this helps.