# How to avoid being crawled/penalized by Google

Tags: django, seo, production-environment, google-index

**OVERVIEW**

I'd like to test some Django websites using random data on a production server using real domain names, but these websites will be simple tests with possible duplicated data (quite probable not following Google rules). I know usually for this you use a development/staging/virtual box for such a task, but I do want to use directly the production box with the real DNS.

Now, I'm kind of new on website development and SEO, and I wouldn't like to mess with SEO and Google.

What'd be the right way to proceed here? Should I try to avoid being indexed/crawled by Google somehow? Any other advices?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390368/stop-google-from-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disallow the complete indexing of your page and then later (when you're done with coding) activate it again.

Thats probably the best way because google is not going to crawl "bad pages" (for example when your website still is in development) and thus you will not get a Ranking so far (called Page Ranking if you want to look it up).

Comment: Ok, I've upvoted you to start with, could you elaborate a little bit further on the **right way** to do this? I mean, I'm a complete newbie on web development as you can see :-)

Comment: @BPL http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html Here is a link where you can read it up. ;P