# How to prevent Laravel application folders from being indexed by search engines

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to key my site's domain into the google search engine and was shocked to realize that the application folders that shouldn't be public have been indexed. Folders and files are like composer.json, a vendor directory, storage directory, resources directory among others.

### How I set up:

The application is in the public_html directory, the index.php is the entry point and is in the root directory(public_html)
The other Laravel application directories remain as they are(the default Laravel 7 directory structure)

Comment: In the docs there is deployment section that describes minimalistic configurations for apache / nginx. You are asking more for devops stuff rather than laravel itself, but you didnt even mention what is the web server

Comment: "The application is in the public_html folder". Well it should not be in that folder. Your domain should point to the Laravel public folder.  The application files should never be in a public folder.

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek The web server is apache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Google from indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390368/stop-google-from-indexing)

Comment: @NicoHaase it would be better to understand why they are indexed in the first place, because if robots can find them, then everybody can

Comment: @toyi yes, you are right, but the title of this question is "prevent from being indexed by search engines". If that is the main issue the OP cares about, this is a dupe

Answer (score 1):

> The application is in the public_html directory, the index.php is the entry point and is in the root directory(public_html) The other Laravel application directories remain as they are(the default Laravel 7 directory structure)

In a default Laravel installation, there is no `index.php` in the project directory, only a `server.php`. If you did any change here, please revert them since it would cause a major security issue.

The only Laravel directory that should be publicly accessible is `public`.

You are using Apache, it means that the `DocumentRoot` should be set to `/path/to/your/project/public` (where `public` is the Laravel `public` directory).

This way, every files and directories (`app`, `resources`...) above this one will not be accessible.

Comment: Okay, probably I should clarify, the issue is not that the files are accessible. They are not accessible but they have been indexed by search engines.

Comment: If these files are not accessible, search engines cannot index them

Comment: yes @NicoHaase is right, there is no way a search engine can index these files if they are not accessible. I think we all agree that these files cannot be accessible and not accessible at the same time, so can you update your question with both your vhost configuration and your entire project directory structure please? It will help a lot

Comment: @iDevsKE That the files are accessible is always an issue. Not only because they get indexed, but also because it's a security risk. So this answer does not only solve the problem in the question, it fixes other problems too.

Answer (score 0):

you should move all your project files to root then copy your files from `public` to `public_html` then point to`public_html` in Laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/public_http';
    });
}
```

Also you can see: [How to change public folder to public_html in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198669/how-to-change-public-folder-to-public-html-in-laravel-5)